# In C#, how do i cope with XmlException: 'xdt' is an undeclared prefix. when trying to set new password in connectionString?

Tags: c#, winforms, configuration

I am trying to set a new password in my app.config files. I tried to do this using code below. Exception is thrown here because of the xdt:Transform in the connectionString:

```
configuration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["DbContext"].ConnectionString 
= string.Format("Data Source=x ;Initial Catalog=x ;User='sa';Password='{0}';", 
textBox1.Text);
```

Reason: "System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: ''xdt' is an undeclared prefix. "

This is a transformed config file and hence contains "xdt:Transform"

Here is the connectionstring I want to change:

```
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="DbContext" connectionString="Data Source=x;Initial 
  Catalog=x;User='sa';Password='x';"
     xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Is there any possibility to somehow parse a connectionString part of the xml file? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you have to do this programmatically? Is this project in a build pipeline?

Comment: Hi, I have to change the db pass every 90 days and have to update new pass in all config files manually (it's a solution containing 8 projects). This is why I'm trying to do this programmatically. And it works just fine if I remove xdt attribute from XML file. I'm out of ideas..I will try tomorrow to figure it out. Thx for reply.

Comment: You might have better luck editing as straight xml instead of using the Configuration API. but if you have a build Pipeline there would be a place to input variables and the pipeline would handle the transforms or token replacements

Comment: Thanks for the idea. it works fine i used linq to xml:
`var connStrXML = xml.Descendants("connectionStrings").Elements().First();
var connStr = connStrXML.Attribute("connectionString").Value;`

i splittet it then into a string array and modified pass.

`string[] arrConn = connStr.Split('\'');`

Answer (score 6):

The xdt namespace should be defined. In the a web.release.config file (*), this is done like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <!--
    in the example below, the "SetAttributes" transform will change the value of a connectionstring
    -->
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="some value" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

*) I must admit that these transformations are normally used for web.config files rather than app.config files. However, it can be done for app.config also, but this is another topic.